# no such module 'Firebase'

Tags: ios, xcode

I've looked through all the related questions on this site and other sites and cannot find an answer. Here is my podlike and the error I'm receiving:

[general code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLWxE.png)

[podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc9p1.png)

When I fully build, the no such module disappears, HOWEVER, as soon as i command shift k to clean the no such module prompt comes back.

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove slash between Firebase/core for firebase dependencies and check.

2.Remove all firebase dependencies and add one by one then check that are you able import.